# PyQT / Windows / Pyinstaller (exe) - NameError: global name 'QtGui' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I have a problem trying to turn my python code into an executable using pyinstaller. I'm using PyQT 4.9.1 and Python 2.7.

I am getting the error when I try and build it (Build.py):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Build.py", line 1494, in <module>
    main(args[0], configfilename=opts.configfile)
  File "Build.py", line 1472, in main
    build(specfile)
  File "Build.py", line 1429, in build
    execfile(spec)
  File "c:\projects\vibot\vibotUI_07.py", line 270, in <module>
    window = viUI()
  File "c:\projects\vibot\vibotUI_07.py", line 9, in __init__
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
NameError: global name 'QtGui' is not defined
```

I have searched google and all the solutions are based on correcting improper importing of modules, but I already did it properly to begin with.

Here is a cropped version of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class viUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        self.setObjectName('viMainWindow')
        self.resize(400, 600)

        self.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = viUI()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the Makespec.py file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis([os.path.join(HOMEPATH,'support\\_mountzlib.py'), os.path.join(HOMEPATH,'support\\useUnicode.py'), 'c:\\projects\\vibot\\vibotUI_07.py'],
             pathex=['c:\\Python\\pyinstaller-1.5.1\\pyinstaller-1.5.1'])
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE( pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name=os.path.join('dist', 'vibotUI_07.exe'),
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're calling Build.py and passing your script as a paramter. I just tested this to see what would happen and got the same output that you posted.

With the current stable PyInstaller (1.5.1) you need to [create a spec file first](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#create-a-spec-file-for-your-project). Instead of Build.py run MakeSpec.py with your script as an argument. This will create a .spec file that you then send to Build.py.

The documentation shows options you can pass to MakeSpec for things like setting an icon under Windows and setting deployment options. These options all go into the spec file so that you just need to call Build.py again when you need to rebuild your application.

Comment: I am using Makespec.py before Build.py, sorry if I left out too much info.

Comment: Are you running Build.py on the .spec file that Makespec.py creates?

Comment: Sure am. I'll edit in the Makespec.py file, I have a feeling maybe I've entered something incorrectly to make it not find the pyqt module.

Comment: Ahh, I misread what you asked, I was running build on the ordinary python file. Sorry about that, my brain has been much lately! Thanks for your help.